# Data from Amazon Kinesis to DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, record, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I have to pass my data from Kinesis to DynamoDB. The problem is that not all the data arrive when my software is running.
So when I restart my application a lot of records are added into DynamoDB.
Now I don't know why the records don't arrived all within run time, but this is a big problem.
The monitoring of resources is good, i tried both InitialPositionInStream.LATEST and InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON without any change.
Is it happened at someone?Is there a solution?
There seems to be a buffer that save record. I used git code of aws.
Maybe be it a network problem?

Answer (score 5):

**Records in Amazon Kinesis are saved for 24 hours.**

If you use `TRIM_HORIZON`, you would start at the oldest record (i.e. up to 24 hours old) and traverse forward from there. 
`LATEST` means you are only interested in records received since you start your new application.

I suggest you use the [Amazon Kinesis Client Library](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client) if you are not already, which will manage the checkpointing of records using a DynamoDB table that it creates for itself to keep sequence. That way, when you stop and restart your application, it will save and resume from the last successfully processed record (This is still in a receive-at-least-once model).

Comment: i used Amazon Kinesis Client, maybe the problem is Kinesis shard, because with 3 shards I write without problem, but when I read I need of 25 shards, I think they are too many but so it seems to work.

Comment: I wonder if it could be that the sequence numbers saved in Dynamo by KCL were too large (Note: KCL will use its last checkpoint if you have run the app before and the dynamo record for the shard exists, not `LATEST` or `TRIM_HORIZON`). This could happen if you re-created the stream and did not clear the contents of the dynamo database that KCL is using. If you really want KCL to start from `LATEST` or `TRIM_HORIZON` then you need to clear the contents of DDB for the stream.

Comment: Pretty much the above, but to add on KCL is a scalable and fault tolerant library that offers and simple interface to process Kinesis records.  I would highly recommend incorporating this into your application, here's a great example of how to use it https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library.

Comment: but if I clear DDB I will start from the first record in the stream (because I delete checkpoints).
I thought that using LATEST I avoid from checkpoints and it gets only the new record, whereas using TRIM_HORIZON the application gets from the first untrimmed record.
But trying they seem equal.

Comment: You are correct about how TRIM_HORIZON and LATEST work. Are you sure that is what you are observing, with multiple records in the stream (after clearing DDB in each case)? Probably you'll need to post your relevant code and how you have tested this

Comment: The problem was checkpoint method, it was called every 10 minutes, too much for my program. 
Another problem was the writing on DynamoDB. Now i'm using only 3 shards but I added a buffer structure beetween DynamoDB and Kinesis, so while the program reading from Kinesis and putting records into buffer, other 30 consumer threads reading data  from buffer and writing in DynamoDB

Comment: 30 consumer threads on 3 shards? That is very likely to be the problem then.. I believe KCL is designed to have 1 consumer or less per shard